# Very high avg_write_stall_ms for tempdb

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, tempdb

What could be causing (and how to fix) my tempdb files (8 equal size) to have [avg_write_stall_ms] of 7300ms and the next  highest data file is 47ms.

System is Hyper-V fail-over cluster, SQL 2012 Standard, 60GB RAM, 20 vCPU, EqualLogic PS6100 SAN

Here's my results from the Glen Berry tools

[image: IO Stalls by File]

I've requested that the tempdb data files be moved to their own drive letter, but am not sure that will help because it would be the same SAN.

Comment: is TF 1118 and 1117 enabled ? Also, is tempdb sharing the same LUN as data / log files ?

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, you have tempdb data files 2GB each. I would suggest you to properly presize them since 2GB is very less. This will prevent expensive autogrowth events which might be contributing to higher stalls. Use [this script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TheRockStarDBA/eac93e53c0f1ed01af37/raw/0906abf6085df2fdb318d6d10d1f97e2581e28c1/AutoGrowth_Events) to know how many times autogrowth event fired. A seperate LUN for tempdb will definitely help. see this as well http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53917/8783

Comment: @Kin, only Trace Flag 1204, 1222, and 3605 are set.  Same LUN as the data files currently.  I also ran that script and there were no autogrowths for tempdb.

Comment: You will need `TF 1118 and 1117 enabled`. I am away from my computer, but read up on those trace flags. Why have you set `TF 3605` - it writes all dbcc output to error log ?

Comment: @Kin Thanks. I've set TF1118 and 1117, but since I haven't had the files grow and they're still all the same size, 1117 won't change anything.

Comment: If it's not due to growth events, then I would say your R:\ and/or the I/O path to it are completely saturated and insufficient for your workload.