# How can I tell if my tempdb database has a performance issue/need to add more data files?

Tags: sql-server, performance, tempdb, performance-tuning

SQL Server works in database called *tempdb* to handle a lot of tasks. Query operations like joins and aggregations happen there. Online index rebuilds, order by, aggregate function, triggers are also done in *tempdb*.

How can I measure when should I add another tempdb data file? And how many tempdb data files are required?

Comment: [SQL Server: Demystifying TempDb and recommendations](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31353.sql-server-demystifying-tempdb-and-recommendations.aspx). Following waits are related o TempDB:  PAGELATCH_EX,  PAGELATCH_UP, CXPACKET

Answer (score 7):

Paul Randal explains how many tempDB files to create here [Correctly adding data files to tempdb](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/correctly-adding-data-files-tempdb/)

> If your server has less than 8 logical cores (e.g. a one CPU server
>   with 4 physical cores and hyperthreading enabled has 8 logical cores),
>   use # tempdb data files = # logical cores, equally sized
>
> If your
>   server has more than 8 logical cores, start with 8 tempdb data files,
>   and add sets of four at a time, equally sized, until the contention is
>   alleviated

Note that it is critical to first alter all existing tempDB files so that they are the same size and with the same AUTOGROW settings before you begin. Then create all new TempDB files with the same size and autogrow settings as the existing files.

As for do you currently have a problem? View your wait statistics and determine your top waits, if PAGELATCH_UP or PAGELATCH_EX are up there then you need to investigate further. Glen Berry has a good query for that included here [SQL Server Diagnostic Information Queries for September 2016](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/sql-server-diagnostic-information-queries-for-september-2016/)

When you notice a slow down on your SQL Server you should return sys.dm_exec_requests wait type and wait resource information, and keep an eye out for pagelatch_* wait types. You can then pass the wait resource through DBCC PAGE to determine the database and internal pages experiencing page latching. You can also use the very useful query by SQLSoldier here [Breaking Down TempDB Contention (part 2)](http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/breakingdowntempdbcontentionpart2) to better determine which, if any, internal database pages are experiencing issues and if adding additional tempDB files is the answer. Assuming that you are seeing pagelatches on the internal GAM, SGAM or PFS pages then you want to keep adding files, based on the above advice until the PAGELATCH_ contention reduces.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to use [sp_WhoIsActive](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TheRockStarDBA/9ef597da7d5b895e4bfc/raw/42e248f8c803b0faafdadcacd4f298232c9ba29a/sp_whoisactive.sql) and [log the output into a table](https://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/) .. especially the `wait_info`. This way you keep a baseline and keep a history of your sql server tempdb contention over time to see if adding extra tempdb file has alleviated the contention or not.

> How can I measure when should I add another tempdb data file?

When you experience LATCH contention which can occur due to 3 “special” page types: [GAM (Global Allocation Map), SGAM (Shared Global Allocation Map), and PFS (Page Free Space)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2006/07/08/under-the-covers-gam-sgam-and-pfs-pages/).

> If you see a lot of lines of output where the wait_type is PAGELATCH_UP or PAGELATCH_EX, and the resource_description is 2:1:1 then that’s the PFS page (database ID 2 – tempdb, file ID 1, page ID 1), and if you see 2:1:3 then that’s another allocation page called an SGAM

.

> And how many tempdb data files are required?

[KB2154845](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2154845) gives an official guidance, but [below is from Paul Randal](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/the-accidental-dba-day-27-of-30-troubleshooting-tempdb-contention/)

> Figure out the number of logical processor cores you have (e.g. two CPUS, with 4 physical cores each, plus hyperthreading enabled = 2 (cpus) x 4 (cores) x 2 (hyperthreading) = 16 logical cores. Then if you have less than 8 logical cores, create the same number of data files as logical cores. If you have more than 8 logical cores, create 8 data files and then add more in chunks of 4 if you still see PFS contention. Make sure all the tempdb data files are the same size too.

So below are the takeaways:

1. Presize your tempdb to [avoid autogrowth events](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53917/8783).
2. Enable [Instant File Initialization](http://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2014/02/18/improving-sql-server-performance-by-using-instant-file-initialization/).
3. Enable TF 1118 - Use Full Extents
4. Enable TF 1117 - Grow all files in a filegroup equally
5. All [tempdb data files should be equally sized](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TheRockStarDBA/a35a8c2e74edab3934c6/raw/cc0cc1ae59d3d04da410bb49491f11761553f915/Create%2520tempdb%2520files.sql).
6. Monitor tempdb contention and follow above advise to add tempdb data files until tempdb contention is addressed.

References :

- [Analyzing Tempdb Contention](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2011/04/21/analyzing-tempdb-contention-a-month-of-activity-monitoring-part-21-of-30.aspx)
- [SQL Server TempDB – Number of Files – The Raw Truth](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2009/06/04/sql-server-tempdb-number-of-files-the-raw-truth/)
- [Troubleshooting: Tempdb Contention](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/the-accidental-dba-day-27-of-30-troubleshooting-tempdb-contention/)
- [Automatic TEMPDB Configuration in SQL Server 2016](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2016/03/17/sql-2016-it-just-runs-faster-automatic-tempdb-configuration/)