# Auto-Growth Events

Tags: sql-server-2014, auto-growth

Do we have a way to prove to somebody that auto-growth events may hurt performance of SQL Server?

Currently I can only know **when** it occurred through `sys.trace` and `sys.fn_trace_gettable`. But of course it will only show the start and end date.

I want to know if there is like where you'll show it that whenever there are auto growth events, one may show occurring slowness in SQL Server.

Comment: If at all there are any Autogrowth events logged in , you can check them in Database standard reports . Right click on Database , look for Reports , Standard Reports and check Disk Usage , only if there are any auto growth events logged only then you can see the data over there else it doesn't show up .

Comment: You can use [my script](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53917/8783) to get autogrowth and how much time it took for that event. This will explain the slowness.

Comment: @Kin, thanks for the script. I will try to study it before firing it in the production. I tested it in the local and on the test environment. Results are quite good.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have a dramatic slow down if you have Instant File Initialization turned on for data growths, but the log will still suspend activity while it grows.  You can insert rows into a demo table via a while loop and track the number of seconds required for the insert.

```
USE [master]
GO
--Create DemoAutoGrow database with autogrowth of data and log to 1gb
CREATE DATABASE [DemoAutogrow]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'DemoAutogrow', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS2016\MSSQL\DATA\DemoAutogrow.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024000KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'DemoAutogrow_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS2016\MSSQL\DATA\DemoAutogrow_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 1024000KB )

GO
---------------------------
use DemoAutogrow
go
--Create a table to track the number of seconds required to insert a large row
CREATE TABLE dbo.Demo_TrackInsertTime
 (InsertSeconds int NULL)  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
----------------------------
--Create a table with a large column 
CREATE TABLE dbo.Demo_Table_1
 (NCHAR_Big NCHAR(4000) NULL)  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
-----------------------------
--set up a while loop to insert 2000 rows and track the number of seconds
--required to insert the data
set nocount on
Declare @BeginTime DateTime
Declare @Counter int = 1
Declare @InsertSeconds int
set @BeginTime = getdate()

while @counter < 2000
begin
set @BeginTime = getdate()

INSERT INTO dbo.Demo_Table_1 (NCHAR_Big) SELECT REPLICATE(N'W', 4000)

set @InsertSeconds = DATEDIFF(second,@beginTime,getdate())

insert into dbo.Demo_TrackInsertTime values(@InsertSeconds)
set @Counter += 1
end

--Select rows from the TrackInsertTime table where number of seconds > 0
--Users would've waited for that event to occur
select * from dbo.Demo_TrackInsertTime where InsertSeconds > 0
```